# How to visualize data that is one-token per row

Tags: data-visualization

My data is organized in two columns, "article" and "ethnicity". Article is binomial, having only two possibilities ("a" or "an"), whereas Ethnicity can be several values. Each row in the data is an individual token, like such:

| Article | Ethnicity |
| --- | --- |
| an | white |
| an | white |
| a | white |
| an | black |
| a | black |

... and so on, for about 1300 tokens.

I used R for regression and found black ethnicity to be a significant factor for "a" tokens over "an" tokens, so I wanted to create a plot which shows "a" tokens vs "an" tokens based on ethnicity, so that the significance of "a" tokens by black speakers would be visualized.

The professor I'm working with said to use a 95% confidence interval box-and-whisker plot (using GraphPad Prism) but he nor I have any idea how to translate my Excel sheet into something that GraphPad can read, or that can be made into a box-and-whisker plot in general.

I have little experience with statistics and even less with visualizing it, so I'm sorry if the question is confusing or if the answer is simple and I just can't see it. What I basically need to know is: how can I visualize this data in a way that highlights the significance I'm trying to show?

Comment: The very first thing to do with such data is display its contingency table (*aka* as a "cross-tabulation").  When it is small it arguably is superior to any graphic.  When it is larger, you have reduced the problem to making a graphical representation of the cell counts.  For unordered categorical data like this, boxplots are useless.  If you have accurately reported your situation, then perhaps this professor needs as much help with statistics as you do, so consider finding someone in your institution who can provide knowledgeable assistance.

Comment: I agree with @whuber.  The data can be reduced to % of `"a"` $= 100 -\ $ % of `"an"` for each ethnicity. The observed counts are needed for (e.g.) a chi-square test;,